# grep case sensitive [A-Z]?

Tags: bash, command-line, grep

I cannot get `grep` to **case sensitive** search with this pattern

```r
$ grep 'T[A-Z]' test.txt
The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog
THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG
```

Comment: This seems to be a bug in at least some versions of `grep`; when you use a range of letters in your regex, the search in case insensitive for all letters but the first in the range. E.g. `echo 's' | grep '[S-T]'` doesn't generate any output, while `echo 't' | grep '[S-T]'` outputs `t`. On the other hand, `echo 't' | grep -o '[S-T]'` doesn't output anything either, which is somewhat confusing. Using `[[:upper:]]` instead seems to solve this problem for the case when the range is `[A-Z]`.

Comment: This is not a bug, this behavior is documented in the man page.  The use of a locale is responsible for this, and the value of the locale is fixed by environment variables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use quotes to prevent the pattern from being matched as a glob to file(s) in the filesystem by the shell. `''`

Use a named character class to guarantee a case-sensitive match. `[[:lower:]]`

Use a quantifier to make matches for more than one character. `\+`

Use anchor(s) to make sure the match is positioned properly. `^`

```
grep '^T[[:upper:]]\+' test.txt
```

The reason that `[A-Z]` isn't working for you is that the way the locale you're using is implemented on your system, that pattern also includes lowercase letters.

Comment: @svnpenn: See [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15980/does-should-lc-collate-affect-character-ranges) and [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19322/why-are-capital-letters-included-in-a-range-of-lower-case-letters-in-an-awk-rege) for a discussion of the issues.

Answer (score 5):

You can set LANG value:

```
$ LANG=C grep 'T[A-Z]' test.txt
THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG
```

Answer (score 1):

```
grep 'T[[:upper:]]' test.txt
grep 'T[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]' test.txt
```